# Re-defined Python function was not executed in Thonny shell

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension, generator

Today I saw a very interesting scene while working on an example of list/generator comprehension. First, I defined a function with list comprehension in Thonny shell:

```
    >>> def myZip(*seq):
            res = []
            for i in range(3):
                res.append([s.pop(0) for s in seq])
                print(seq)
            return res
```

When I called the function, I got

```
    >>> g=myZip([1,2],[3,4])
    ([2], [4])
    ([], [])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<pyshell>", line 4, in myZip
      File "<pyshell>", line 4, in <listcomp>
    IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Then, I re-defined the function with generator comprehension:

```
    >>> def myZip(*seq):
            res = []
            for i in range(3):
                res.append(s.pop(0) for s in seq)
                print(seq)
            return res
```

However, when I called the function again, I got the same output.

```
    >>> myZip([1,2],[3,4])
    ([2], [4])
    ([], [])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<pyshell>", line 4, in myZip
      File "<pyshell>", line 4, in <listcomp>
    IndexError: pop from empty list
```

which means the new definition of the function was not executed. I typed the new definition again in the shell and called the function once again. The correct output came up.

```
    >>> myZip([1,2],[3,4])
     ([1, 2], [3, 4])
     ([1, 2], [3, 4])
     ([1, 2], [3, 4])
    [<generator object myZip.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0382DEB0>, <generator object myZip. 
    <locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0382DD30>, <generator object myZip.<locals>.<genexpr> at 
    0x0382DE30>]
```

I spent the whole day trying to figure it out but without a clue. No typos were found. I don't know why I have to redefine the function twice before the new definition becomes effective. To investigate, I restarted a new session: first defined the myZip() function with list comprehension, then re-defined it with generator expression in the shell, nothing wrong happened. The new definition of the function was executed immediately after the enter key was hit. I repeated the whole process several times and always got the expected output. Does it mean the shell sometimes (or rarely) missed execution due to some reason, for example, related to runtime or a crash?

Comment: I don't understand: with that input the function _has_ to crash, due to the `for i in range(3)` - no matter what?

Comment: Python shell does not do that, actually no interpreter does that. If the function was not defined at the first evaluation then you might have misspelled something.
Either you got some syntax error that you missed or you used a different function name.
Can you reproduce it with an plain function that prints "hello" ?

Comment: Ok so the question is not *reproducible*. Instead of suspect random bit flip in your computer why don't you suspect random typo in the programmer instead.